# INSERT query cycling through multiple select array doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a form with a multiple select input that passes its content via an array to php.  I can't get the INSERT query to work, and my only return data to ajax gives me an empty alert box.  I've narrowed it down to the php file, so I'm not going to attach the form or jQuery code.  Any help would be appreciated.

-->"member" is the array passed from the multiple select.

```
$tmid = $_POST["team"];
$fltid = $_POST["flight"];

if ($con) {
if(isset($_POST["member"])){
    $i = 0;
    $members = ($_POST["member"]);
    foreach ($members as $member) {
        $memarr = explode('*', $member);
        $memid = $memarr[0];
        $indid = $memarr[1];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO FlightJoin (FlightID, MemberID, TeamID, IndID) VALUES ('$fltid', '$memid', '$tmid', '$indid')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $i++;
    }
    if($result){
     echo $i.'manifests successfully created.';
    }else{
     echo 'Problem occured adding record.';
    }
}else{
    echo 'data not received.';
}
}
```

Comment: If the script is complete and you don't see anything, the problem is in your db connection or in js code. Have you tested database connection? You have php error reporting activated? if you put `echo 'Hello World'` at top of your script can you get it in js side?

Comment: Yes, I get that returned in my alert box.  My db connection is good.

Comment: So you have a fatal error, because your code echo something in any case. Check your apace error logs.

Comment: Caught it.  mysqli_error needed a connection argument.  Thanks for the help.